# Visual Studio 2013. Code Snippet. Diseñar

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013

Al momento de acceder a generar mis propios fragmentos de código (Snippets) desde el mismo visual studio me lanza la siguiente ventana.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error no es muy explícito. ¿Conocen alguna forma para solucionarlo? o ¿Saben de alguna alternativa para crear mis propios snippet para C# y .net 4.5?

Comment: Intenta buscar los logs de Visual Studio, generalmente allí llega la info de los errores; si no, Intenta también ejecutar VS con el parámetro /Log (Funciona para VS 2015).

Comment: Hace rato que no utilizo VS 2013, pero me parece que los snippets los puedes dejar en una carpeta en la carpeta de documentos del usuario actual (x:\Users\{user}\Documents\Visual Studio X\Code Snippets) y VS los toma automáticamente de allí

Comment: El log trae información de hace 6 días; este error no cae en el log. Sí tengo el acceso a las carpetas de Code Snippets. Lo que no tengo es una herramienta para generar los propias.